# Excluding files/directories from Gulp task

Tags: requirejs, gulp, minify, uglifyjs

I have a gulp rjs task that concatenates and uglifies all my custom .JS files (any non vendor libraries).

What i am trying to do, is exclude some files/directories from this task (controllers and directives).

**Heres my tree:**

```
 - application
    - resources
      - js
        main.js
        - vendor
            - jquery
            - modernzr
            - angular
        - controllers
            - controller1
            - controller2
            - controller3
        - directives
            - directives1
            - directives2
            - directives3
        - widgets
            - widget1
            - widget2
            - widget3
            - widget4
        - modules
            - modules1
            - modules2
            - modules3
            - modules4
```

**Here my gulp.js**

```
dir = {
    app:        'application',
    dest:       'dest',
};

config = {
    src: {
        js: dir.app + '/resources/js'
    },
    dest: {
        js: dir.dest + '/resources/js'
    }
};

gulp.task('rjs', function() {

      rjs({
            baseUrl: config.src.js,
            out: 'main.js',
            name: 'main',
            mainConfigFile: config.src.js + '/main.js',
            exclude: [ 'jquery', 'angular']         
        })
        .pipe(prod ? uglify({ mangle: false, outSourceMap: true, compress: { drop_console: true } }) : gutil.noop())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest.js))
        .pipe(filesize())
        .pipe(dev ? connect.reload() : gutil.noop());

});
```

Comment: Have you tried gulp-ignore? https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ignore

Comment: @user1655734 : the gulp-ignore documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ignore) suggests the exclude pattern (`gulp.src(['./*.js', '!./node_modules/**'])`) first, then gulp-ignore

Answer (score 577, accepted):

**Quick answer**

On src, you can always specify files to ignore using "!".

Example (you want to exclude all *.min.js files on your js folder and subfolder:

```
gulp.src(['js/**/*.js', '!js/**/*.min.js'])
```

You can do it as well for individual files.

**Expanded answer:**

[Extracted from gulp documentation:](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options)

> gulp.src(globs[, options])
>
> Emits files matching provided glob or an array of globs. Returns a stream of Vinyl files that can be piped to plugins.

glob refers to **node-glob syntax** or it can be a direct file path.

So, looking to [node-glob documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob) we can see that it uses the minimatch library to do its matching.

On [minimatch documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#comparisons-to-other-fnmatchglob-implementations), they point out the following:

> if the pattern starts with a ! character, then it is negated.

And that is why **using ! symbol will exclude files / directories from a gulp task**

Comment: Shouldn't this be avoided?

This is from the node-glob documentation:
`Negation

The intent for negation would be for a pattern starting with ! to match everything that doesn't match the supplied pattern. However, the implementation is weird, and for the time being, this should be avoided. The behavior is deprecated in version 5, and will be removed entirely in version 6.`

Comment: I needed to use: `gulp.src([/*file globs*/], {base:"."})` in order to get the glob patterns to work correctly.

Comment: @Scott: yeah, but that have nothing to do with this answer/question.

Comment: @MisterOh: thats what the documentation says. I did research trying to find the right way, but no idea yet. I opened an issue (https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/201) and still waiting for an answer. As soon as we know the preferred way, I will update my answer. In the meantime, I think this answer is still valid.

Comment: @avcajaraville I agree that your answer is totally valid. I was not able to get the posted response working correctly without what I responded in my comment. Not sure how that has nothing to do with the answer/question, but just wanted to post what worked for me.

Comment: @MisterOh actually, gulp.src is vinyl-fs.src, which passes the globbing off to glob-stream, which in turn uses [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for the positive globs and [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) for the negative globs, so it's ok to use negative patterns. Check out the [glob-stream documentation and sample positive and negative glob patterns here](https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream), or [have a look at the code](https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream/blob/799c843870735021613b37fb486b7545a6cb3ea0/index.js#L91).

Comment: Negation is the right way to do this. The gulp documentation was incorrect. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1296) regarding the docs and submitted [PR](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/pull/1299) that has [corrected documentation](https://github.com/breyed/gulp/blob/patch-1/docs/API.md).

Comment: @EdwardBrey Amazing job ! Thanks so much, this really helps on clarify !

Comment: i just get this error 'Error: Missing positive glob'. Code gulp.src([globs.images] , {base:"."}). globs.images works fine when not in[globs.images].

Comment: @v3nt, my guess is your glob.images is already and array, so no need for brackets there. ;)

Answer (score 16):

Gulp uses micromatch under the hood for matching globs, so if you want to exclude any of the .min.js files, you can achieve the same by using an [extended globbing](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch#extended-globbing) feature like this:

```
src("'js/**/!(*.min).js")
```

Basically what it says is: grab everything at any level inside of **js** that doesn't end with ***.min.js**

Comment: This works for folders, unlike the accepted answer.