# How to gulp ignore files with a specific pattern?

Tags: gulp

How do I tell gulp to ignore all files beginning with a "_", es. `_colors.styl` from compiling?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding files/directories from Gulp task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an exclamation point.

You can do `gulp.src(['src/*.styl', '!src/_*.styl']);`

or `gulp.src(['src/*', '!src/_*']);`

Answered here: [Excluding files/directories from Gulp task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task)