# What does "!" mean in file paths?

Tags: gulp

I am reading over someone's `gulpfile.js` that I found, and came across an interesting character that I've not seen in file paths before; the `!` symbol. I tried to do some searches for this but yielded nothing.

```
gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

Does the `!` have some particular meaning, here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding files/directories from Gulp task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Gulp, but a [quick search](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/A+Tutorial+for+Getting+Started+with+Gulp) shows that it tells gulp to ignore a given path.

> Prepending a path with an exclamation mark tells Gulp to exclude that directory.

So, in your example, `paths.minJs` should be excluded from the task Gulp is performing.

---

Actually it is used to negate a pattern, based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648667/2088822) to another question. That is, it is used to select what does not match the following pattern. As a consequence, it ignores the path in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I read over it several times but that line just never jumped at me.

Comment: Note that if your task has to compile js into minified js, you would rather use 2 differents folders. As an example, a folder /source/js/ whose files are compiled in min.js into /dist/js/ ( or /public/js/ or anything you want ).

Comment: you have saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Additionnaly to my above comment that I report here:

*Note that if your task has to compile js into minified js, you would rather use 2 differents folders. As an example, a folder /source/js/ whose files are compiled in min.js into /dist/js/ ( or /public/js/ or anything you want ).*

This a piece of code I often use to concatenate and uglify my Js files in most of my projects:

```
// My task called jsmin depend on another task, assume it is called clean but could be whatever
// That means that until the clean task is not completed, the jsmin task will not be executed.
gulp.task( 'jsmin', ['clean'], function() {

    // First I clean the destination folder
    del([ 'public/js/*' ]);

     // Then I compile all the Js contained in source/js/ into min.js into public/js/
     // In my example I concatenate all the Js together then I minimize them.
     return gulp.src( 'source/js/*.js' )
    .pipe(concat( "js.min.js" ))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'));
});
```

Hope that helps you.