# How to prevent gulp from creating vendor and app files

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'm not sure if I'm correct or not but it seems that my gulp setup automatically creates a vendor.JS with all the dependencies I have in my bower.JSON and an app.JS with all th JS files i have on my project.

Both files are also uglified.

Is there a way to prevent that behavior and just get all the JS files injected in the index.HTML ?

Comment: Post your gulp configuration file.

Comment: Gulp is just a task runner. Probably this is some gulp module that is doing that. Could you please add your configuration here?

Comment: You're probably using [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) (or similar) in your gulp task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. If you want to set order of downloading scripts, you can use [gulp-rigger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rigger).

After installing it you can create `main.js` file and set there:

```
//= path/to/script1.js
//= path/to/script2.js
...
//= path/to/scriptN.js
```

Next just uglify only this file.

Second. If you want to exclude files from gulp task processing, you can use next:

```
gulp.src(["/your_scripts_dir", "!your_scripts_js/*.min.js"]).
    .pipe(...)
    ...
```

See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648667/5397119