# Select folder other then

Tags: javascript, gulp

On a Gulp task to merge JS files I have the following which is working:

```
var root = "/app/scripts/"

gulp.task("build:scripts", function () {
  return gulp.src(
    [
      root + "jquery.js",
      root + "angular.js",
      root + "app.js",
      root + "app.config.js",
      root + "*/*.service.js",
      root + "*/*.controller.js"
    ]) 
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dist))
    .pipe(rename("app.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dist));
});
```

But I need to first select the files in shared folder and then the others:

```
var root = "/app/scripts/"

gulp.task("build:scripts", function () {
  return gulp.src(
    [
      root + "jquery.js",
      root + "angular.js",
      root + "app.js",
      root + "app.config.js",
      root + "shared/*.service.js",
      root + "shared/*.controller.js"
      root + "!shared/*.service.js",
      root + "!shared/*.controller.js"
    ]) 
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dist))
    .pipe(rename("app.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dist));
});
```

But this is not selecting the files that are not in shared folder.

Why is !shared not working? Should not this work?

**UPDATE**
I also tried

```
"!" + root + "shared/*.service.js",
```

and

```
root + "[^shared]*/*.service.js",
```

But none of them worked.

Comment: We need more information for this. Which is that task implementation ? How you add those files there ?

Comment: @avcajaraville I just updated my question. Is more complete now. Is this what you meant? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the '!' to the beginning of the path:

```
gulp.task("build:scripts", function () {
  return gulp.src(
    [
      root + "jquery.js",
      root + "angular.js",
      root + "app.js",
      root + "app.config.js",
      root + "shared/*.service.js",
      root + "shared/*.controller.js"
      root + "shared/!(*.service).js",
      root + "shared/!(*.controller).js"
    ]) 
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dist))
    .pipe(rename("app.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dist));
});
```

See this [SO for details on `gulp.src`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task?answertab=votes#answer-24648667). Note the quote:

> if the pattern starts with a ! character, then it is negated.

#### Edit

I've changed to code above after I had the time to test this.
You can use the negation option with parenthesis. So `root + !(*.service).js` will exclude all `.js` files ending with `.service`.

Further more you can combine the two last excludes into one like so:

```
root + "shared/!(*.service|*.controller).js
```

Comment: That won't work because root is "/app/scripts/". So I need all files that are not in folder "/app/scripts/shared" but are still inside scripts.

Comment: Did you try it?
The exclude options is still considering the entire glob, not just the first part of a path, as far as I know.

Comment: In my case it did not work ... What I am trying is to first add all JS files in shared and after it all JS files outside of shared but still inside scripts. I added 2 updates to my question which I tried but did not work ...

Comment: @Miguel I've updated the answer after testing. This should work.