# Gulp concat - all files except for some

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, gulp-concat

I've been searching a while for this but with no luck.

I'm trying to write a gulp task that should concatenate all js files inside my lib folder, except for some.

I tried with the following, using gulp-ignore, but with no luck:

```
var gulpIgnore = require('gulp-ignore');

var ignoreIonic = '!./www/lib/ionic/';

gulp.task('unify-libs', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.libs)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ngAnnotate({
            single_quotes: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(ignoreIonic))
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js'));
});
```

My folder structure is the following:

```
www
 |--lib
    |--ionic
    |   |--css
    |   |--fonts
    |   |--js
    |   |   |--angular
    |   |   |--angular-ui
    |   |   |--ionic.bundle.js
    |   |   |--ionic.bundle.min.js
    |   |   |--ionic.js
    |   |   |--ionic.min.js
    |   |   |--ionic-angular.js
    |   |   |--ionic-angular.min.js
    |   |--scss
    |--test.js
```

What i'm trying to achieve with the gulp task is:

I wanna concatenate all files inside **lib folder**, but inside ionic->js i want to concatenate only **ionic.bundle.min.js** to the final javascript and NOT all the files.

Any help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, i solved in this way:

```
var paths = {
    libs: ['./www/lib/**/*.js', '!./www/lib/ionic/**'],
    ....
};

gulp.task('unify-libs', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.libs)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ngAnnotate({single_quotes: true}))
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/' + appRelease + '/js'));
});
```

and it is now compiling all files inside `lib` folder, except for any file inside ionic folder. I just decided to copy the only file i needed directly in my src folder, it makes my life easier.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

My help is not straightforward but might prove better in the long run. I would suggest not reinventing the wheel and make use of proven packages for mobile app developing. There is a great [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) Geneator out there which will deliver an ionic starter project from scratch with all extras like gulp minification included: 
[generator-m-ionic](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i've spent some time to tune this to properly work as i need, and the only thing left to do is this concatenation thing..
i should have probably used the tools you provided before, but right now i don't really want to start everything again

Comment: reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task offers the answer i think it should be: gulp.src([path.libs, ignoreIonic])...

Comment: are you sure path.libs is not empty?

Comment: then i think you should concat your two arrays first, I think gulp src expects **one** array as argument https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#globs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102496/discussion-between-nick-and-user9).