# Gulp copy min file but not js/css

Tags: node.js, gulp, glob

I'm trying to copy all my assets into my public dir but I want all assets except JavaScript and CSS files cause they are concatenated and minified into `prod.min.js` and `prod.min.css` so I want to make two exception for `min.js` and `min.css` files.

I have tried this (only for JS for now)

```
gulp.src([src + '/**/*', src + '/**/*.min.js', '!' + src + '/**/*.js'])
          .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
```

But it results in no JavaScript files at all.

How can do this?

Comment: Maybe you can find answer on your question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task

Comment: Thanks ! I see this answer but I want the exact opposite :D but can't manage how do it :(

Answer (score 0):

Create separate glob arrays for CSS and JS. Then you can be more selective in which get moved.

Comment: I can separate into 2 glob but my question will be the same, I want to exclude all js (or css) files except .min.js  (or .min.css)

Comment: Isn't it a case of just having `'/**/*.min.js'`

Comment: no cause I want to copy all other assets like images, fonts... just want to know if there a way to do it in one task instead of 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

I am also dealing with this problem at the moment.

The way I patched it (*it's a patch because it's not really an optimal solution*) is by making two passes:

1. First pass -> move all (`**/*.*`) files and negate all js extensions (`!**/*.js`)
2. Second pass -> move only the minified files (`**/*.min.js`)

A quick task example:

```
gulp.task('move-min-not-src', [], function() {

    var paths = [
        [
            'source-folder/**/*.*',
            '!source-folder/**/*.js'
        ],
        [
            'source-folder/**/*.min.js'
        ]
    ];

    paths.forEach(function(path) {

        gulp.src(path)
            .pipe(
                gulp.dest('destination-folder/')
            );

    });

});
```