# Gulp watch all LESS files in root

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

looking to watch all the less files in the root gulp project directory and then compile only the saved LESS file. I can't get past the first part.

When I run $ gulp watch in the project directory it hangs. Starts the task and never finishes.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('compileCurrentTheme', function () {
 return gulp.src('./*.less')
 .pipe(less({
  compress: true
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Gulp watch functions
gulp.task('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch('*.less', ['compileCurrentTheme']); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some mistake

```
gulp.task('compileCurrentTheme', function () {
  return gulp.src('./*.less') // ./ -> root directory
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('yourPath')); // you can also type ./ it will create .css files in your root directory
});

// Gulp watch functions
gulp.task('watch:less', function(){
  gulp.watch('./*.less', ['compileCurrentTheme']); 
});
```

***Rename*** your `watch` task to `watch:less` and then run it from your console `gulp watch:less`

Please look at [gulp-less](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less) and [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) especially `gulp-watch` just to make your understanding a bit clearly.

I hope it will help you

Thanks

Comment: Updated my code to reflect your suggestion. Still hangs.

[14:48:16] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/gdw/thedentalsitecontent/themes/gulpfile.js
[14:48:16] Starting 'watch'...

Comment: @JustinWHall Does it re-run `compileCurrentTheme` task when you press save?  *Starts the task and never finishes* - because gulp is waiting for your changes that's why it doesnt finished. This is normal behavior

Comment: Actually, this works. It appears gulp is getting hung up on something else in that directory.

Comment: No. I can run the **compileCurrentTheme** task manually. The **watch** task hangs.

Comment: Actually, I was incorrect before. It works. The watch task just takes a really long time to run. There are a few hundred directories in the root of this project. Is there a way to exclude them from the watch so this executes faster? So just watch the root directory?

Comment: @JustinWHall yeap [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task) is the link

Comment: This doesn't seem to have an effect on the watch task time. `gulp.watch(['*.less', '!./*' ], ['compileCurrentTheme']); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105951/discussion-between-the-and-justin-w-hall).