# With Gulp is there a way I can exclude a folder from gulp.src?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have this gulp:

```
return gulp.src('content/less/*/*.less')
```

Is there a way that I could exclude the folder

```
content/less/info from the .src search?
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A glob that begins with `!` excludes matching files from the glob results up to that point. For example:
The following expression matches a.js and bad.js:

`gulp.src(['client/*.js', '!client/b*.js', 'client/bad.js'])`

Ref: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#globs