# Why isn't my Gulp excluding a file?

Tags: gulp

Looking at this SO answer: 
[Excluding files/directories from Gulp task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task)

It appears that I need to negate my file with a !.  I have the following Gulp file:

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(['content/**/*.css', '!content/login.css'])
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(uglifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

My debug shows that login.css is being included.

> ...
>   [19:52:49] gulp-debug: content\LineItems.css
>   [19:52:49] gulp-debug: content\Login.css
>   [19:52:50] gulp-debug: content\NavBar.css
>   [19:52:50] gulp-debug: content\NewCompanySite.css
>   ...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Gulp is case sensitive.

I changed:

```
return gulp.src(['content/**/*.css', '!content/login.css'])
```

to

```
return gulp.src(['content/**/*.css', '!content/Login.css'])
```

and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Why not change the filename to `login.css` instead? If you require that all static resources are lowercase-with-hyphens you (or someone else) won't run into this problem again