# Gulp: Include folder tree, except one folder

Tags: gulp

I want `gulp.src` to include all file and folders in `src` directory, except for `src/devpackages` directory, so that the `src/devpackages` directory is not copied with `gulp.dest`. How can I do that? I tried with `gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/devpackages/**'])`, but the `gulp.dest` creates the `src/devpackages`, but leaves it empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding files/directories from Gulp task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task)

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I am not asking for any rjs thing, I am asking for gulp.src. Please see the edit and let me know if you can help.

Comment: The linked question is not an "rjs thing". The accepted answer explains how to use ignore patterns in `gulp.src()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gulp.src([
    baseDir + '/**',                              // Include all
    '!' + baseDir + '/src/devpackages{,/**}',               // Exclude devpackages
], { dot: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion here : [excluding folders from globs][1].  You can do it by 
this:

```
gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/devpackages{,/**}'])
```

That is shorthand for exclude the folder and exclude the files it contains, you need to do both.

[**EDIT**] Oops, sorry - I missed that the previous answer had this idea already (although a little over-complicated).

1]: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/165