# Gulp src double negation

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

in my gulp task I would like to exclude all *.js files, except *.worker.js files, so I did this:

```
path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.!(worker.)js')
```

Unfortunately this excludes all files, including my worker files. Maybe you could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try putting it like this:

```
gulp.src([conf.paths.src + '/**/*.js', '!' + conf.paths.src + '/**/*.worker.js')])
```

That way, you have separate strings for separate inclusion/exclusion rules. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648667) for details.