# exclude a file from gulp compilation

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a gulp file that looks like this,

```
    const paths = {
  styles: {
    src: 'src/styles/**/*.scss',
    dest: 'dist/styles',
  },
  javascript: {
    src: 'src/scripts/**/*.js',
    dest: 'dist/scripts',
  },
  copy: {
    pluginsFile: 'src/scripts/plugins.js',
    pluginsFolder: 'src/scripts/plugins/**',
    mapsFolder: 'src/scripts/maps/**',
  },
  files: './**/*.php',
};

    function javascript() {
  gulp
    .src(paths.copy.pluginsFolder)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.javascript.dest}/plugins`));

  gulp.src(paths.copy.pluginsFile).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.javascript.dest));

  gulp
    .src(paths.copy.mapsFolder)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.javascript.dest}/maps`));

  const jsFiles = glob.sync(paths.javascript.src);

  return browserify({
    entries: jsFiles,
    transform: [babelify.configure({ presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] })],
  })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.javascript.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

I have a file in in 'src/scripts/visualiser.js' that I want to exclude from going into my bundle how would I go about that?

I have since changed my paths object to be the following,

```
const paths = {
  styles: {
    src: 'src/styles/**/*.scss',
    dest: 'dist/styles',
  },
  javascript: {
    src: ['src/scripts/**/*.js', '!src/scripts/three-d-scripts.js'],
    dest: 'dist/scripts',
  },
  copy: {
    pluginsFile: 'src/scripts/plugins.js',
    pluginsFolder: 'src/scripts/plugins/**',
    mapsFolder: 'src/scripts/maps/**',
  },
  files: './**/*.php',
};
```

I know get the following gulp errors,

TypeError: glob pattern string required

This is from this line,
`const jsFiles = glob.sync(paths.javascript.src);`

changing this line to,

`const jsFiles = paths.javascript.src;`

returns the following error,

Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module '/Users/simon/Sites/website/website/wp-content/themes/storefront-child-website/!src/scripts/three-d-scripts.js' from '/Users/simon/Sites/website/website/wp-content/themes/storefront-child-website/!src/scripts/_fake.js'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excluding files/directories from Gulp task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384239/excluding-files-directories-from-gulp-task)

Comment: @Krullmizter Please see question edit.

Comment: Is `jsFiles` an array? Can you just `.filter` to remove the one you want to not include?

Comment: could you try to write the path like this one? `!./src/scripts/three-d-scripts.js`